# Unable to make field private static final java.util.HashMap java.lang.ProcessEnvironment.theEnvironment accessible

Tags: java, scala, sbt

When I run sbt, I get the below. I am still able to keep working but the warning/error annoys me and clutters my terminal. Any idea how I resolve this?

```
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private static final java.util.HashMap java.lang.ProcessEnvironment.theEnvironment accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @43016
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:172)
        at au.com.onegeek.sbtdotenv.DirtyEnvironmentHack$.$anonfun$setEnv$1(DirtyEnvironmentHack.scala:42)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
        at au.com.onegeek.sbtdotenv.DirtyEnvironmentHack$.setEnv(DirtyEnvironmentHack.scala:38)
        at au.com.onegeek.sbtdotenv.SbtDotenv$.configureEnvironment(SbtDotenv.scala:71)
        at au.com.onegeek.sbtdotenv.SbtDotenv$autoImport$.$anonfun$dotEnv$1(SbtDotenv.scala:42)
        at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:49)
        at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:49)
        at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:49)
        at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:49)
        at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:49)
        at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:49)
        at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:49)
        at sbt.Project$.setProject(Project.scala:501)
```

Comment: Seems that you run an older version of sbt on a newer Java/JVM version. There is a reference to "scala.runtime.java8", but the executing Java/JVM is cleary something 9+ (it uses modules …). I would suggest you do an upgrade somewhere.

Comment: Seconded. Try a newer sbt version such as 1.6.1. What version are you using currently?

Comment: I'm already using 1.6.1 with openjdk 17.0.1 2021-10-19 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu17.30+15-CA (build 17.0.1+12-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu17.30+15-CA (build 17.0.1+12-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: Does the error happen when trying to load **sbt** or when you try to `compile` or `run` your code? If the former, what is your **Scala** version?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is coming from `sbt-dotenv`.

At the root folder of your project, just create a `.jvmopts` file containing the following lines:

```
--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
```

Answer (score 2):

The stack trace mentions "au.com.onegeek.sbtdotenv", so apparently this is coming from https://github.com/mefellows/sbt-dotenv.

You could try upgrading to the latest version of that plugin and see if the problem goes away.

If it doesn't, you could report the issue to the maintainer.

In that repo's README, there is a section about similar errors:  https://github.com/mefellows/sbt-dotenv#illegal-reflective-access-warnings

It isn't clear to me if that's the same or different.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `sbt-dotenv` is the culprit, you can try a couple of things:

1. Create a `.jvmopts` and place it at the root folder of your project.
2. Prefix the `export` keyword in your `.env` variables.

This should solve the issue